# Socket.io alternative for tcp server

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, socket.io

So.. I was looking for a nodejs package that works with tcp servers but the `net` package does not handle messages as events. I'm looking for something like `socket.io` but works with tcp servers/clients, handles messages as events and has good tutorials online.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library called pusher. You should check it out.

https://pusher.com/